# What does とした mean?

Tags: particles, verbs

I've seen this question on Yahoo and couldn't figure out what とした exactly meant.

> デスノートの主人公、夜神月（ヤガミ・ライト）ですが、この名前、なかなか素敵でミステリアスで良いと思いますが、実際に自分の子供に「月（読み方はライト）」**とした**場合役所では、認めてもらえるのでしょうか？

Comment: If you really named your child "Raito", would the government recognize it?

Comment: @Dav7n And how do you think とした contributes to  your translation?

Comment: AをBとする means to make A B. So, 名前を月とする means to make his name 月.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 実際に自分の子供を「月（読み方はライト）」とした場合、役所では認めてもらえるのでしょうか？

=実際に自分の子供の名前を「月（読み方はライト）」**とした場合に**（**と、設定した場合に**）（**と、決めた場合に**）、役所の戸籍係では、認めてもらえるのでしょうか？

～とした
＝～と　した（”する”の過去形）

~と＝as

した＝did, made, decided

*If I **decided** my child's name **as** "月 (the pronunciation of it is raito) ," would the authority admit the name?*

Comment: "実際に自分の子供**を** " -- でも、原文は「実際に自分の子供**に** 」ですよね・・

Comment: 原文の「に」はtypoと解釈しました。その方が、「とした」の説明が分かりやすいだろうと思ったからです。